# Как при вызове OnLongClickListner не вызывать OnClickListener

Tags: android, onclicklistener

У меня есть такой код:

```
b.setOnLongClickListener(v -> {
               //...
            return false;
        });
b.setOnClickListener(v -> add(v.getId()));
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы при вызове OnLongClickListner не вызывать OnClickListner

Comment: Возвратить true из setOnLongClickListener?

Comment: Подскажите, что означает b.setOnClickListener(v -> add(v.getId()));?

Comment: @ArtyMorris 
b - это переменная в которой храниться View, а setOnClickListener ставит на это View слушатель, который вызывает функцию add() при нажатие на это View

Comment: Не понял до конца, но спасибо )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вернуть значение "true" из setOnLongClickListener